# Syntax error after yum update on PHP

Tags: php, syntax-error

I had an old version of a CMS which was working on PHP 5.3.3-27 Build Dec 11 2013 .
I had run a yum update and my PHP has been gone to PHP 5.3.3-27 Build Aug 6 2014.
The exact version with different build time
But now the same code of my CMS does not work and give me : 
"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in" some of my files.

Comment: PHP Parse errors are caused by PHP source code. You should have the exact file and line number in the error message; please read it completly.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrading your PHP back to the previous version

```
sudo yum downgrade php
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me error about dependencies.